# How to write multiline in Cloudera QuickStart Terminal?

Tags: bash, apache-spark, terminal, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I want to write multiline using | in the terminal. I am using Cloudera quickstart VM.

```
val csv = spark.read.option("header",true).option("inferSchema",true).csv("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/spark/dataset/retail_db/categories-header")
```

I am writing this full in single line. How to write using multiple line ? Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\`. For example:
`data = [1,2,3].\ pop()`
After `\` you can move on to the next line

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that when the cursor is between () we can use press enter and it will take us to next line .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using spark-shell, you can do like this

> val csv = spark.read.
> option("header",true).
> option("inferSchema",true).
> csv("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/spark/dataset/retail_db/categories-header")

Press Enter key after each dot. However if you are using pyspark you have to escape it using \